# Need to do assert inside public void testWhenRespWriterIsNull() throws IOException

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

I want to write assert inside the below IOException.

```
public void testWhenRespWriterIsNull() throws IOException {
    when(response.getWriter()).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    when(request.getParameter("version")).thenReturn(null);
    logoutServlet.doPost(request, response);
    exceptionRule.equals(IOException.class);
}
```

UPDATE: I am getting following error in SonarQube

> Add at least one assertion to this test case.

As I am new to JUNIT , so I do not know which assert I need to write inside the above `testWhenRespWriterIsNull()`.

Comment: Dear All , Anybody can please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It you already have `exceptionRule.equals(IOException.class);`, there is no need of any other Assert statement. This statement validates that `IOException` is thrown.

You might want to test for error message in the exception thrown, by

`exceptionRule.expectMessage("For input string");`

For more examples related to asserting exceptions in Junits, check out [Junit Assert Exceptions](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception)

Comment: Thanks...When i am running my code in sonarqube then I am getting below assert error "Add at least one assertion to this test case". I added below line in the code.                                                                                                                        
 public void testWhenRespWriterIsNull() throws IOException {
    when(response.getWriter()).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    when(request.getParameter("version")).thenReturn(null);
    logoutServlet.doPost(request, response);
    exceptionRule.equals(IOException.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull("version");}

Comment: I have added Assert.assertNotNull("version"); to above and after that I am not getting sonar qube issues.  But I am not sure that is it correct to write  Assert.assertNotNull("version");  "or' something else I need to do ?

Comment: This is a work around. And I think this sonar warning is kind of a false positive. May be you can mark it as 'will not fix' on sonar. Also, it would be worth checking the sonar source code or documentation to find out which all statements are considered valid assert statements.